# Deleting database from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, mstest

I have an MDF file that I'm attaching to my local SQL server during testing with MSTEST and I don't want to have to go delete those temporary databases by hand after I've run the test set 50 times. (I've already done that and I don't like it >.<)

I'm look for a way to delete the database from the server after I'm done with the tests, during my `TestCleanup` method. I just need a little guidance on what SQL statements I would use to do this.

**EDIT** (By Software Monkey, from OP's rejected edit to ODED's answer)

Here is the code which worked for me:

```
var server = new Server(serverName); // Can use overload that specifies 

foreach (Database db in server.Databases)
{
     if (db.Name.ToLower().Contains(testDatabaseIdentifier))
     {
          databasesToDelete.Add(db.Name);
     }
}
databasesToDelete.ForEach(x =>
{
     Database db = new Database(server, x);
     db.Refresh();
     db.Drop();
});
```

Comment: Do you mean delete the actual MDF file? You would use ordinary file deletion methods from the framework for that. If you mean deleting the tables in the MDEs, it's a simple series of `DELETE FROM tableName` statements.

Comment: I rembered investigating something similar a while back and ended up using SQLCE for my automated tests. Would this be an option for you, too?

Comment: @Robert, sorry about that I should have specified. Not the mdf itself, but just the db that was created when I attached the mdf

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at the [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) (SQL Server Management Objects) .NET wrappers.

These allow you to manage all aspects of SQL Server from code, including deleting of databases.

The database object has a [`Drop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.drop.aspx) method.

The code below is to illustrate how you could use the object model, though I have not tested it:

```
var server = new Server(serverName); // Can use overload that specifies 

foreach (Database db in server.Databases)
{
     if (db.Name.ToLower().Contains(testDatabaseIdentifier))
     {
          databasesToDelete.Add(db.Name);
     }
}
databasesToDelete.ForEach(x =>
{
     Database db = new Database(server, x);
     db.Refresh();
     db.Drop();
});
```

Comment: Iterating over server.Databases was the key for me. I can work out the rest from here. Thx!

Comment: @Mike - glad this will be of help :)

Comment: I made a few changes to the code since dropping the db in the foreach modifies the collection, causing an exception. Also, I found that just dropping the db without refreshing the it also causes an exception.

Comment: Should this work if the Windows UAC is enabled on a user's PC?  I've tried this method before, and it does not work consistently.

Comment: @RLH - It does require that the account the application runs under has the right permissions.

Comment: All of my users are admins on their PCs but I've had issues that almost always originate with the UAC.  If the UAC is left at a default semi-high level of security, the user has rights to drop the DB but the UAC somehow halts the process.  My application gets an exception, but it's pretty generic.  I only know that the UAC is the problem by experience.  Is there a way to check the UAC settings before the drop, and prompt the user?  Can I integrate some form of permission elevation into my application, temporarily?

Comment: @RLH - I don't know. Why ask questions in comments instead as actual questions?

Comment: I did, but I'm still fishing for answers on related questions.  My question is a bit bigger than this, though.  I've tried a lot of solutions over the years to get this to consistently work.  Nothing has been "perfect".  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969215/how-to-delete-a-sql-server-2005-express-database-using-c-sharp-and-windows-uac

Comment: Sorry, one more comment.  This was my initial method for dropping the local database.  I moved to the "Server.KillDatabase" approach because it became more consistent.  I can't recall where (probably on MSDN) but someone had actually mentioned that Server.KillDatabase was a better approach, anyway.  Still, I don't care how this problem is solved.  I just want to be able to reliably drop a local database, on various types of Windows machines, when the user is guaranteed an admin on the machine and *should* have all necessary rights to delete a database.

Answer (score 10):

Try with this:

```
sqlCommandText = "DROP DATABASE [NAME]";
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText , connection);
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I think this would help.

Comment: For EntityFramework Code First, you can use this:`_db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, "use master; drop database [mydatabase]"`.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using the `Database` type to delete a database in TestCleanup, I would recommend to use the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server.KillDatabase` method. In addition, this will close all existing SQL connections before the database is deleted. Thus your unit tests (or rather integration tests) might leave connections open and this will have no effect on the cleanup method.

```
var server = new Server(SqlServerName);
server.KillDatabase(DatabaseName);
```

Answer (score 6):

feO2x's answer works great but he didn't give code. The following works if you have your database connection string in your app.config.

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
public class Foo
{
    public static void DropDatabase(string connectionName)
    {
        using (
            var sqlConnection =
                new SqlConnection(
                    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName]
                    .ConnectionString))
        {
            var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(sqlConnection);
            var server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(
                             serverConnection);
            server.KillDatabase(sqlConnection.Database);
        }
    }
}
```

You must reference *System.Data*, *System.Configuratio*n, *Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo*, *Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc*, and *Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo*.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you do it using Entity Framework version 6

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.Delete(connectionString);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. That's what I want!

Answer (score 3):

**I.  Create Resources file (Resources.rsx) and write sql queries:**

- SQL_KillConnections

---

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName nvarchar(50)
SET @DatabaseName = N'{0}'
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL,'') + 'Kill ' + Convert(varchar, SPId) + ';'
FROM MASTER..SysProcesses
WHERE DBId = DB_ID(@DatabaseName) AND SPId <> @@SPId
EXEC(@SQL)
```

- SQL_DropDatabaseIfExists

---

```
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='{0}')
DROP DATABASE [{0}]
```

**II. Add MsSqlDatabaseTestsHelper class into the test project**

```
public class MsSqlDatabaseTestsHelper
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public MsSqlDatabaseTestsHelper(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    private void ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    public void CreateDatabase(string databaseName)
    {
        ExecuteNonQuery("CREATE DATABASE {0}".Set(databaseName));
    }

    public void DropDatabase(string databaseName)
    {
        try
        {
            ExecuteNonQuery(Resources.SQL_KillConnections
                .Set(databaseName));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("Can't kill database '{0}' connections"
                .Set(databaseName));
        }

        try
        {
            ExecuteNonQuery(Resources.SQL_DropDatabaseIfExists
                .Set(databaseName));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("Can't drop database '{0}'"
                .Set(databaseName));
        }
    }
}
```

**III. Use database helper in your unit tests**

```
[TestFixture]
public class CmsPageRepositoryTests
{
    private readonly MsSqlDatabaseTestsHelper _msSqlDatabaseTestsHelper = 
        new MsSqlDatabaseTestsHelper(ConnectionStringWithoutDatabase);

    private const string ConnectionStringWithoutDatabase = 
        @"server=.\SqlExpress;uid=sa;pwd=1;";

    private const string DatabaseName = "TestPersistence";

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _msSqlDatabaseTestsHelper.DropDatabase(DatabaseName);
        _msSqlDatabaseTestsHelper.CreateDatabase(DatabaseName);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _msSqlDatabaseTestsHelper.DropDatabase(DatabaseName);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestSomethingWithDatabaseUsing()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or try this

```
       var  sqlCommandText = "DROP DATABASE [dbName]";
       var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
       var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText, sqlConnection);
       sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
       sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```