# Reliably drop a database on SQL Server 2008 via C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am currently trying to drop a database via the following code

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

var server = new Server(Server);
server.KillAllProcesses("Db");
server.KillDatabase("Db");
```

Sometimes it works, but others I get the following exception:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Kill database failed for Server 'Host1'.
> ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. 
> ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Changes to the state or options of database 'Db' cannot be made at this time. The database is in single-user mode, and a user is currently connected to it.

Any ideas of how to reliably drop the database via code?

Comment: Did you try `ALTER DATABASE Db SET MULTI_USER;` first?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't use SMO for this, mainly because I don't know exactly what those `Kill...()` functions do. I would rather say `USE master; ALTER DATABASE Db SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; DROP DATABASE Db;`

Comment: The database is not set as SingleUser by default, I think that a failed attempt on the KillDatabase method is turning it into a Single User and then leaving it like that.

Comment: Just run profiler while using KillDatabase.. this is what I get(among other things).

    ALTER DATABASE [Db] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    ....
    DROP DATABASE [Db]

Comment: So, how, exactly was this solved?  I'm having this exact same problem, except I use SQL Server Express 2005?  Historically, I've used this method (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170429/deleting-database-from-c-sharp), which I have found to be only slightly more reliable that `Server.KillDatabase`.  However, the `DROP` method hasn't been 100% reliable, either.  How did Konstantinos fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reliably delete the database via SMO it is sufficient to call `server.KillDatabase("Db");`. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.killdatabase.aspx) does state that `KillDatabase` drops active connections even if their examples are a bit misleading.

`KillDatabase` issues `ALTER DATABASE [Db] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` and then `DROP DATABASE`. `KillAllProcesses` list all connections and issues one kill per process as a separate batch; assuming `KillAllProcesses` is asynchronous the exception is thrown when a kill happens after `KillDatabase` sets the DB to the single-user mode.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error I was getting was fixed by adding server.Databases.Refresh before the KILL method.  The reason for it was the database I was trying to drop was created after the Server object was instantiated, in other words I was creating a database temporarily, extracting data from it and dropping it.  The database was not showing up on the list of Databases (object).  Adding refresh did the trick...

Answer (score 1):

I've got error (" drop failed...")
Using MSDN:

```
dbServer.KillAllProcesses(db.Name);
dbServer.KillDatabase(db.Name);
```

The work around was:

```
string sqlCommandText = @"USE master; 
ALTER DATABASE [" + db.Name + "] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 
DROP DATABASE [" + db.Name + "]";  
dbServer.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlCommandText);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed such error by creating ServerConnection without pooling. Like this:

```
var serverConnection = new ServerConnection(serverName)
{
     ...,
     NonPooledConnection = true
};
server = new Server(serverConnection);
server.KillAllProcesses(databaseName);
```