# Dropping SQL Server database through C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008

I am using this code to delete a database through C#

```
Int32 result = 0;

try
{
        String Connectionstring = CCMMUtility.CreateConnectionString(false, txt_DbDataSource.Text, "master", "sa", "happytimes", 1000);

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = Connectionstring;

        String sqlCommandText = "DROP DATABASE [" + DbName + "]";
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlConnection.ClearPool(con);
            con.ChangeDatabase("master");
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText, con);
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            con.ChangeDatabase("master");
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText, con);
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }



        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
        result = 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result = 0;
    }
    return result;
```

But I get an error

> *Database currently in use*

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which line gives an exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170429/deleting-database-from-c-sharp

Comment: sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); gives the exception

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen your solutions works. Thanks

Comment: See [Deleting database from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19049344/240845) for an answer with code.

Comment: What is CCMMUtility?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try this:

```
String sqlCommandText = @"
ALTER DATABASE " + DbName + @" SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
DROP DATABASE [" + DbName + "]";
```

Also **make sure** that your connection string defaults you to the `master` database, or any other database other than the one you're dropping!

As an aside, you really don't need all of that stuff around your queries.  The ConnectionState will always start off `Closed`, so you don't need to check for that.  Likewise, wrapping your connection in a `using` block eliminates the need to explicitly close or dispose the connection.  All you really need to do is:

```
String Connectionstring = CCMMUtility.CreateConnectionString(false, txt_DbDataSource.Text, "master", "sa", "happytimes", 1000);

using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring)) {
    con.Open();
    String sqlCommandText = @"
        ALTER DATABASE " + DbName + @" SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
        DROP DATABASE [" + DbName + "]";
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText, con);
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
result = 1;
```

Comment: I needed to put brackets [] around the `DbName` of the alter statement to, I had some dashes in my DbName (GUID). Then it works like a charm.

Comment: SqlCommand inherits IDisposable implementation from its parent class and should be protected in a using block.

Answer (score 27):

Here is how you do it using Entity Framework version 6

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.Delete(connectionString);
```

Comment: Are you kidding me! I couldn't find this anywhere online. In shock that this is not higher voted.

Comment: That's the best answer for me!

Comment: This needs Entity nuget reference?

Comment: @Sandy Yes, you need to add the EntityFramework 6 Nuget package
`dotnet add package EntityFramework`
Or the EntityFramework Core Nuget package
`dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look at [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).
These allow you to manage all aspects of SQL Server from code, including deleting of databases.

The database object has a [Drop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.drop.aspx) method to delete database.

Comment: Beware referencing SMO dlls in project that are not compatible with production environment.

Comment: @MicahEpps: Why ?

Comment: Beware referencing SMO dlls in project that are not compatible with production environment because if you have, say, SS version A installed on your development environment, and you deploy to a customer who has version B, then the dlls will not load.

Answer (score 2):

Create sqlconnection object for different database other than you want to delete.

```
sqlCommandText = "DROP DATABASE [DBNAME]";
sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCommandText , sqlconnection);
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This is what I have pasted in the question.

Comment: Create sqlconnection object for different database other than you want to delete.You can't delete database using the connection of same db.

Comment: I have changed the database using  con.ChangeDatabase("master");

Answer (score 2):

In this case i would recommend that you take the database offline first... that will close all connections and etc... heres an article on how to do it: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/04/24/sql-server-t-sql-script-to-take-database-offline-take-database-online/

Microsoft clearly states that `A database can be dropped regardless of its state: offline, read-only, suspect, and so on.` on [this MSDN article (DROP DATABASE (Transact-SQL))](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178613.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Connection pooling at a guess, use sql server's activity monitor to make sure though.

Pooling keeps connections to the database alive in a cache, then when you create a new one, if there's one in the cache it hands it back instead of instantiating a new one. They hang around for a default time, (2 minutes I think) if they don't get re-used in that time, then they killed off.

So as a first go connect straight to master, instead of using change database, as I suspect change database will simply swap connections in the pool.

Add a check routine for database in use (use a connection to master to do it!). You can force the database to be dropped anyway by first executing

```
ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

again from the connection to master!

However everybody else using the db, will no longer like you at all...

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use DB name in connection string.

```
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same troubles as Anshuman...
By my testing of the code in question of Anshuman there have been very simple error:
there have to be `SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();` instead of `SqlConnection.ClearPool(con);`

Like this trouble of

> "cannot drop database because is in use..."

disappears.