# Drop/detach database from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, detach

I have a program that does a lot of configurations on the executing system, sharing folders, checking firewalls, looking for orphaned databases and much more.
One thing it does is that it looks for databases where the MDF file has been deleted. I want the program to detach or drop the database with the missing MDF. The program uses SMO for database operations.

I've tried the following

```
string sqlCommand = string.Format("DROP DATABASE [{0}]", databasename); 
server.KillAllProcesses(databasename);
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlCommand);
```

and

```
server.DetachDatabase(databasename, false);
```

and

```
string dbQuery = string.Format("ALTER DATABASE \"{0}\" SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ALTER DATABASE \"{0}\" SET SINGLE_USER EXEC sp_detach_db '{0}'", databasename);
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(dbQuery);
```

No matter what I do to try to drop or detach the database I get an exception:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ExecutionFailureException: An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Unable to open the physical file "masked file name". Operating system error 2: "2(The system cannot find the file specified.)".
>          vid Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
>          vid Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)

Is there any other way to do this programmatically or am I going about things the wrong way?

Comment: Can you try doing it manually inside management studio, does that give you errors?

Comment: This could be what you need: [Dropping SQL Server database through C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069661/dropping-sql-server-database-through-c-sharp)

Comment: Yes, I've tried doing it in SSMS and that works as long as the database hasn't gone into state Recovery Pending.

Comment: Rigerta - Yes I've looked at that site and tried those thing but the result is almost the same.