# How to delete a dynamically generated database file (.MDF and .LDF) from the filesystem and from SQL server using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I m generating a database file  dynamically to a specific location on a button click.
And I delete the database dynamically by using File.Delete() function which deletes the .MDF and .LDF file from that location. 
But when I m trying to create the database again with the same name... It throws an error of "Database already exists. Choose a different name".
Is there any other way of completely deleting that database file from the file system?

Comment: did you drop the database from sql first?

Comment: I don't know how to drop the dynamically created database from SQL server. I m deleting the MDF and LDF files directly from the folder where they are stored. 
I would appreciate if I get the code to drop a database dynamically from the SQL server itself.

Comment: There are issues when deleting databases with SQL Server.  The permissions get changed.  It is better to un-mount the database and then mount a replacement.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using File.Delete(), ask SQL Server to drop the database. During drop operation it deletes the related files. ie:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(@"server=.\SQLExpress;Trusted_Connection=yes"))
{
   con.Open();   
   new SqlCommand("drop database myDbName", con).ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Cetin. That really helped. Now the databases are getting dropped directly from the SQL server itself. THANK YOU BUDDY!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this SO question: [Deleting database from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170429/deleting-database-from-c-sharp)

There are examples on how to delete the database from SQL server through C#.

Comment: Yes I tried this piece of code too. But I m not able to find the libraries required for the Server() class in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Have you had a look on NuGet? https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=SQL+SMO There is an unofficial one from Microsoft which I have just tried that has the functionality.